# Why can't I enter 500 in a HTML5 number field?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I keep getting strange unexpected validation errors with my HTML5 number field. This is my HTML code:

```
<input type="number" name="width" maxlength="5" placeholder="Width" value="733.95591182365" />&nbsp;Width<br />
```

When I enter 500 and submit the form, I receive the error: "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 499.95591182365 and 500.95591182365."

**I've solved the problem.** The problem was this `value="733.95591182365"`. I've altered my PHP code to round decimals to integers so that only integers can be echoed into the number field. Now I only receive errors when decimals are entered, which is OK.

Comment: `maxlength` does not apply to number inputs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have `step="any"` as an attribute when working with `type="number"`

```
<form>
  <input step="any" type="number" name="width" maxlength="5" placeholder="Width" value="733.95591182365" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct because that would also work, but I solved the problem by rounding the width to an integer before echoing it.

Comment: That step="any" should've really been default for type="number". Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For [number inputs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)),

> The [step scale factor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step-scale) is 1. The [default step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step-default) is 1

Then, since there is no [`step`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-step) attribute, the [allowed value step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step) is `1×1 = 1`:

> 1. If the attribute is absent, then the [allowed value step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step) is the
>      [default step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step-default) multiplied by the [step scale factor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step-scale).

And the [step base](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-min-zero) will be `733.95591182365`:

> 2. If the element has a [`value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute, and the result of applying the [algorithm to convert a string to a number](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-value-string-number) to the
>      value of the [`value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute is not an error, then
>      return that result and abort these steps.

Therefore,

> **Constraint validation**: When the element has an [allowed value step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step), and the result of applying the [algorithm to convert a
>   string to a number](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-value-string-number) to the string given by the element's
>   [value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) is a number, and that number subtracted from the [step
>   base](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-min-zero) is not an integral multiple of the [allowed value step](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-step),
>   the element is [suffering from a step mismatch](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#suffering-from-a-step-mismatch).

Since `733.95591182365 - 500 = 233.95591182365` is not a multiple of `1`, that constraint is violated.

If you want another step, specify a [`step`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-step) attribute. If you don't want any step, use `step = "any"`.